# Forces on ball thrown inside fighter cockpit during a manoeuvre

Tags: experimental-physics, aircraft

In a fighter aircraft, if pilot throws a ball vertically inside cockpit, and carries out a '6 g' turn, will the ball also undergo 6g force?

Comment: While the ball is in the air, it is in free-fall. The ball isn't accelerating, the plane is.

Answer (score 0):

Not until the ball is in contact with part of the plane - the pilot's lap, in this case. From the pilot's point of view the ball will be thrown upwards and behave exactly as it would doing the same on the surface of the Earth, but as soon as the 6g maneuver is initiated the ball will fall with 7g of acceleration relative to the pilot. And possibly leaving him/her with a sore crotch. Hence "check for loose objects" is an important part of checklists.

Note that the ball doesn't accelerate faster downwards, the aircraft accelerates faster upwards.

(I'm assuming the 6g is directed downwards from the pilots point of view, and the 6g is is addition to the normal 1g in straight and level flight. I'm also ignoring the fact that the force of gravity is *slightly* less for an aircraft at altitude.)